Runtime text uses more space than shown in designer in Visual Studio
In VS 2022 running on Win 11 on an ASUS laptop with default 125% scaling, text placed in a label occupies more space at runtime than is shown in designer. The text font appears to be larger.The design time image is shown below:

The runtime image where the text in the label occupies more space than in the designer is shown below:

In response to dr.null comments:
Visual Studio 2022 Winforms using .Net 4.7.2
I cannot see any way of accessing ApplicationHighDpiMode/DpiAwareness within VS
Changing the container form AutoScaleMode to DPI fixes the length problem  but creates another in that the default button height is insufficient to show all of the text as shown below.
AutoscaleMode Font:

AutoScaleMode DPI

If the button AutoSize property is set to true, the second problem is fixed and the runtime form is reasonably similar to that shown at design time:


Which .NET version and what's the app's ApplicationHighDpiMode / DpiAwareness setting? You should have it set to PerMonitorV2. Also, set the AutoScaleMode property of your container controls (Form, UsetControl...) to Dpi.

Follow the steps High DPI support in Windows Forms. Add app.config file (if you don's have one already) and insert <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" /> entry into the <System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection> as shown there. Skip the manifest file since you're using .NET 4.7+.
